# CSS background, PNG has white line where transparency starts

Tags: css, photoshop, retina-display

I'm getting a strange white border on PNG images along where the transparency starts on retina devices when using the images as a background with CSS. Is there any way to get the white border to go away?

```
.background {
    background: url('../image.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You may want to save this as a PNG with 8-bit transparency. This can be selected through Photoshop's Save For Web dialog.

Answer (score 3):

Was able to figure out a fix for anyone else that runs across this problem.

I created a media query for retina devices and changed the image rendering.

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
  .background {
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
  }
}
```